# Amazon PHP SDK S3 'waitUntil' object exists

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I need some assistance clarifying syntax of the AWS SDK 'wait' behavior. I'm not sure how to handle failure states after a maximum number of retries. That and most of the AWS examples use a 'bucket exists' and I need to wait on an object existing.

We have a thumbnailer on lambda that creates a thumbnail of an image. It checks any new created object events and if the file type is an image, it tries to create a thumbnail of it.  We then use a rest call to retrieve the thumbnail upon request for the user interface.

The problem is that there is a delay sometimes before the thumbnail is generated and my current code either retrieves the thumbnail or sends a default 'red x' if no thumbnail exists.

What I would prefer to do is use the 'waitUntil' the object (thumbnail) exists.  The naming pattern is to add _{width}x{height}_thumbnail.jpg on whatever the original basename of the file was. w/h is currently 150 so I can predict the thumbnail name.

The current code in the thumbnail rest script is:

```
if($s3Client->doesObjectExist($bucket, $thumbnail_key)) {
    $signedUrl = $awsSvc->getSignedDownloadUrl($userId, $bucket, $thumbnail_path);
    $redirectUri = $signedUrl['uri'];
} else {
    $redirectUri = "/images/finao/icons/no-file.png";
}
```

But I would prefer to replace the doesObjectExist with a waitUntil object exists. (obviously if it existed right away, it would proceed - but I still need to return the no-file.png if a timeout is reached. Say, 5 seconds)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I was able to determine that the default behavior is to throw an exception if the retry/timeout is reached. I am currently catching the exception to send the necessary redirect (conditional upon the exception being 'retry exceeded') but would be interested if there is a better way to handle this as 'do this if exists', 'do that if retry exceeded'